# Optional / consuming optionals and returning another Optional

Tags: java

I'm running into a problem where I guess I would need something like `orElseMap(...)`/`orElseFlatMap(...)`.

I'm consuming an optional from a method invocation. If that Optional is empty I want to retrieve another Optional from another method. Then I want to return an Optional describing if a value has been found through one of the two calls or not.

Am I just missing something?

So I want to do something like:

```
public Optional<Foo> getSomething()
{
  final Optional<Foo> foo = service.getFooFromBla()

  if (foo.isPresent())
    return foo;
  else
    return service.getFooFromBlubb();
}
```

I'm not really satisfied with the above solution, but maybe it's the only working thing right now. Usually if I want to unwrap I'm using `map(...)`/`flatMap(...)` in combination with `orElse(...)`/`orElseGet(...)`, which is really concise.

but I'm missing the method `orElseMap(...)` and `orElseFlatMap(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

Ah well, just found out that Java 9 [added](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-optional) the [`or(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#or-java.util.function.Supplier-)-method which is precisely what I wanted (which is not available in Java 8, that's why I had no clue).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do that with Java8 : both `orElse` and `orElseGet` are returning a `String` , you can wrap them into an `Optional`, something like

```
public Optional<Foo> getSomething()
{
     return Optional.ofNullable(service.getFooFromBla().orElse(service.getFooFromBlubb()));
}
```

Comment: The problem is that they are also both returning an `Optional<Foo>`. But as of Java9 I think they added the `or(...)`-method which is what I wanted :-)

Comment: Wasn't that what you were looking for? *Then I want to return an Optional describing if a value has been found through one of the two calls or not.*